# Random, unique letter and digits for each row

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate a random value for each row/input I receive but I end up generating the same value in each row.

```
import random
import string
import pandas as pd


file=pd.read_csv('url short.csv')
p=len(file.index)
for i in range(p):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits
    result_str = ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(4))
    print(result_str)
    file['short'] = result_str
    
print(file)

Output:

    #         link short
0 NaN  youtube.com  rr4v
1 NaN   google.com  rr4v
```

Comment: It's just overwriting the entire column for each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Doing `file['short'] = result_str` assigns the same value to all rows (broadcasting).

What you should do:

```
import random
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits

file['short'] = [''.join(random.choices(letters, k=4)) for i in range(len(file))]
```

*NB. you should avoid using `file` as variable name, this is a python builtin*

Comment: This fixed it but when I re-run the code the values for previous rows change too, is there any way I can fix the random value for a row?

Comment: @Rohit you did not say you wanted to run many times. That said, you have several options: the simplest might be to add this short id to potential new rows **before*" you add them to the feels y. An otter option is to pre-generate a  fixedlarge list of IDs that you will slice Rm when you need it. Please provide more information on how your data changes.